# on.input is too fast! Is there an Event for Multi-Character-Input? ..or a way to add a Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some ajax code that updates a doc in the db

```
  // Updates to INPUTS, on.input..
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on('input', '.updateThisClass', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var number = $this.data('id');
        console.log("index # of doc updated: " + number);
          //THIS IS LOGGED WITH EVERY CHARACTER ENTERED

        // make an ajax call
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#theForm' + number).serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:9999/update",
            success: gotAllSuccess,
            error: gotAllFailure
        });

    });
})
```

.input is too fast though, and updates on every single character!

How can a Timer be added to the .input part of this function? Or is there an event for multi-char-inputs?

Comment: You want to "debounce" the event.  See this plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: In addition [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) has a number of helpful function functions like [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) and [throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

Comment: @RocketHazmat awesome! am reading up on this right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to "debounce" the event function.  This will wait until the user has finished inputting text before running the function.

It's normally done using `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout`.  You clear and re-set a timeout each time the event runs.  Then when the event stops triggering, the function runs (after the timeout period).

Here's an example:

```
$('#input').on('input', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);

    clearTimeout($this.data('timeout'));

    $this.data('timeout', setTimeout(function(){
        console.log($this.val());
    }, 250));
});
```

If you like, there is also a jQuery plugin that can take care of the timeouts for you.  Here's a link: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Using the plugin, the code would look like:

```
$('#inputC').on('input', $.debounce(250, function(e){
    console.log($(this).val());
}));
```

Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KP5rM/1/